# Does WCF require to publish metadata at production-time?

Tags: wcf, metadata, production

When at design-time, WCF must publish MEX or WSDL to allow clients auto-configure their proxies; but when design-time is over and the service and clients are going to run in production, is it still required that a service publish its metadata?

Comment: No, it is not required.

Comment: Could you please direct me to a documentation where this is stated? I have already used Google with no luck. I just read about this in a WCF book. **"Though WCF services always have metadata, it is possible to hide the metadata
from outsiders. If you do so, you have to pass the metadata to the client side by
other means. This practice is not common, but it gives your services an extra layer
of security."**

Comment: I don't know what you expect to see. Try it and find out.

Comment: You're right about trying it out, but I asked because I'm really new to this WCF thing. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: New or not, what do you expect to see?

Comment: I'd really like to see a Microsoft's documentation page where this behavior [Metadata is not required at production-time and configured clients will continue to work w/o WCF publishing metadata] is documented.

Comment: Metadata is not used at runtime. .NET is not PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found what I was looking for.

According to [**"WCF Security Guidelines"**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648370.aspx) provided by Microsoft , under *"Proxy Considerations"* it is stated:

> *Proxy Considerations*
>   **Publish your WCF service metadata only when required.**
>   If you need to publish your WCF service metadata, publish it over the HTTPS protocol.
>   If you need to publish your WCF service metadata, publish it using a secure binding.
>   If you turn off mutual authentication, be aware of service spoofing.

Comment: This is the exact location of the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650142.aspx#ProxyConsiderations1